# Hide / show navigation on scroll with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in jQuery which works well, but I'm trying to transform it to vanilla JS (plain JavaScript), at first I will show you code in jQuery:

```js
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('.nav');

$window.on('scroll', function(){
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  height: 8000px;
}

.nav {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.nav.hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="nav">Scroll to show/hide this bar!</div>

<p>They see me scrolling...</p>
<p>Scroll down and back up to view the nav</p>
```

and here is code in vanilla js I made getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object Window]' is not a valid selector.

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = document.querySelector(window);
var nav = document.querySelectorAll(".nav");

$window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var scrollTop =
    window.pageYOffset ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
    document.body.scrollTop ||
    0;

  if (scrollTop > prev) {
    nav.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }

  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

Can someone tell me where I am making a mistake please.

```
var prev = 0;
var nav = document.querySelectorAll(".nav");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var scrollTop =
    window.pageYOffset ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
    document.body.scrollTop ||
    0;

  if (scrollTop > prev) {
    nav.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }

  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

We solve problem on window object, but now we get another error on classlist toggle like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')

Comment: The error message is very clear.  Your code starts with querySelector(window), but "window" is not a valid selector.  Remove that line of code and change $window to just window on the line down.

Comment: You'll also find jquery helpfully hides the distinction between a single element and an element collection (by always being a collection and having methods apply to the collection).   The next error you'll get is `nav.classList.` as classList isn't a property of a `NodeList`

Comment: @Yogi you're right, it solve error at first, but now i get another issue just like freedomn-m tell us, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')"

Comment: @freedomn-m sir can you tell me how can i do it? maybe in a for...of loop... in with classList.add and classList.remove or better NodeList.forEach() method.

Comment: Please don't ask a question, get an answer, then edit your question with a new question. Ask a new question with your new question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for guide me on forum :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all querySelectorAll returns all the elements in an array.
Since you only have one .nav bar you can just change it to `.querySelector(".nav")` instead.

And also the scroll will not work as expected.
You can't use `.toggle("hidden");`. When you use toggle you are constantly telling the navbar to show and hide every time you scroll.

If you are scrolling down, we add hidden class `nav.classList.add("hidden");`
If you are scrolling up we remove hidden class `nav.classList.remove("hidden");`

```
var prev = 0;
var nav = document.querySelector(".nav");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || 0;

  if (scrollTop > prev) {
    nav.classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("hidden");
  }

  prev = scrollTop;
});
```